# Is it possible to remove logo and the top header section in lightning /or if any alternative available

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Attached is the below screenshot, i want to remove the top section highlighted in red.

I have tried and researched , but i couldn't get any resolution and seems to be a limitation at this pt of time.

If anyone have any other approach/workaround, will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: One of the options could be to have a visualforce page to be shown without standard header and navigate directly to that page. Then there will be no lightning header shown

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to suppress or alter the Lightning Experience header or sidebar. This behaviour is intentional. Apps that display in Lightning Experience are Lightning Experience apps. If you need to provide a completely custom interface for your app, you’ll need to run it in Salesforce Classic.

In particular, the showHeader and sidebar attributes of apex:page have no effect on Visualforce pages when displayed in Lightning Experience.

Reference:- [Know Which Features to Avoid in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_known_issues)